# How to get information from child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a `Users` model with `has_many :comments`
Each comment records the `current_user` to the `commenter` column.

How can I call @commenter.username in my view and show the commenter's username?

Currently in comments_controller using: `@commenter = User.find("2")` will pull the correct information. I would like to use something along the lines of: `@commenter = User.find_by_id(:commenter)`

Comment: Can you provide some actual code (e.g. model code) ? It's really hard to understand what your model relationships look like reading this.

Comment: Also your db schema would help. I don't understand why you're using `commenter` as your column name, the standard format would be `user_id` for a `belongs_to` relationship.

Comment: @ChrisSalzberg Sorry for the confusion, I am using user_id to match the comment to the user's page, commenter is solely for the user who posted the comment. Additionally there is no model code for comments besides the belongs_to/has_many

Comment: Although I posted an answer to this question, you really need to provide more detail because it's very hard to understand what you are asking. At least provide a db schema for the `comments` and `users` tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you have this `Comment` model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The comment model represents *comments on a user's page*, where the user model is defined as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

There is also a `commenter` column on the `comments` table to store the user who posted the comment (on the other user's page).

First, I would recommend using `commenter_id` for this column rather than `commenter`, since this is the convention for storing ids of any kind.

Assuming that you have a `commenter_id` column on the `comments` table, you would then define a *second* relationship as follows:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commenter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :commenter_id
end
```

The `commenter` relationship defines the user who *wrote* the comment, rather than the user *whose page the comment is on*.

For the other side of this relationship, update your `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :page_comments, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :commenter_id
end
```

Here, `page_comments` defines the comments this user has posted on other users' pages.

Then if you have a `@comment`, you can get the commenter's name with simply:

```
@comment.commenter.name
```

As long as you setup your column names and models correctly, dealing with getting information like this should be very simple.

Comment: This worked but without the @ symbol, just `comment.commenter.username`

Comment: Great to hear that!